# Open Source alternatives to FF Tisa fonts

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation

Recently, I have stumbled upon the FF Tisa fonts quite often and I happen to like them. Unfortunately, I have not found a matching open source alternative yet.

FF Tisa Pro:

[image: FF Tisa Pro 1]
[image: FF Tisa Pro 2]

FF Tisa Sans Pro:

[image: FF Tisa Sans 1]
[image: FF Tisa Sans 2]

<sub>Pictures from the myfonts.net entries of the fonts</sub>

The following fonts seem quite close to FF Tisa Pro:

- Neuton (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Neuton)
- Gentium Book Basic (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Gentium+Book+Basic)
- Vollkorn (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Vollkorn)

And other ones close to FF Tisa Sans Pro:

- Alegreya Sans (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Alegreya+Sans)
- PT Sans (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/PT+Sans)

Unfortunately, it is very hard to find a good pairing to replace the Tisa combination, because either the weights differ too much or the character widths feel wrong. Do you have any recommendation for a good pairing?

Answer (score 3):

[PT Serif](https://fontlibrary.org/es/font/pt-serif) and [PT Sans](https://fontlibrary.org/es/font/pt-sans) from fontlibrary.org

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. This definitely is a good combination. It's unfortunate, that PT Serif has such a open Q and cornered C, but one cannot have everything :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is from a while ago – I found it when I was also searching for a font like Tisa Pro.

In the end, I was quite satisfied with [Andada Pro](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Andada+Pro?category=Serif&stylecount=9).
This being for anyone else with the same question:)